# excel javascript add-in accessing microsoft graph api

Tags: office-js, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to host a javascript application written in angular which talks with Microsoft graph api, inside excel javascript add-in.

Application is hosted properly inside excel -add-in.

But when I call login method I get below error
Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=1e…20directory.readwrite.all%20contacts.readwrite%20files.readwrite.appfolder' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The login page cannot be hosted inside a frame / add-in directly. You need to create a popup window that hosts the login screen, and then sends the access token back to the add-in after the user has completed the sign-in process.

There are more details about how to do this on this MSDN topic: [Use the OAuth authorization framework in an Office Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt629180.aspx).